# How to get global variables from jbpm-process within WorkItem

Tags: java, jbpm, kie, kie-workbench

I can successfully retrieve global variables (such as NodeInstance, ProcessInstance and so on) from within the process with help of Script-Task and kcontext-instance; But what if I need retrieve those global variables within WorkItem? I could of course put Script-Task before my WorkItem within Process and then assign a global variable to one of Variable Definitions, in order to use it within WorkItem with getParameter()-method;

But we do understand, that it is double made work, doesn't we?
So how could I get global variables within WorkItem without additional Script-Task? I thought firstly, that I could use the same name of the session within WorkItem, such we define by registering WorkItem in KieWorkBench, that's why I created a ProcessContext within my WI as follows:

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-process");
ProcessContext context = new ProcessContext(kSession);
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

public void executeWorkItem(WorkItem workItem, WorkItemManager manager) {

    params.put("lane", context.getNodeInstance().getNode().getMetaData().get("Lane").toString());
    manager.completeWorkItem(workItem.getId(), params);

}
```

With this code snippet within executeWorkItem(), but rather with kcontext in Script-Task I can retrieve successfuly the name of the Lane and assign it to variable, but when I execute the process with this WorkItem I get an Error - WorkItem -- null not by deploying, rather by starting the process; Of course I also registry the same ksession - name as within WorkItem (namely "ksession-process") in KieWorkBench, but apparently I cannot use the context this way, as I thought.

So I really appreciate your help! It doesn't really bother, but to make a code resp. BProcess a little bit concisely and without any redundant variables, it pays to ask.

jBPM 6.4, wildfly 8.2

**UPDATE:**
as user livthomas has suggested, instead of WorkItemHandler interface I've tried to extend my class to AbstractWorkiItemHandler as follows:

```
public class WI extends AbstractWorkItemHandler {

public WI(StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession) {
    super(ksession);
}

KieSession kSession = getSession(); 
ProcessContext context = new ProcessContext(kSession);
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

public void executeWorkItem(WorkItem workItem, WorkItemManager manager) {
    params.put("lane", context.getNodeInstance().getNode().getMetaData().get("Lane"));
    manager.completeWorkItem(workItem.getId(), params);
}
...
```

And then register it in Project's descriptor.xml as new my_package.WI(ksession); 
Unfortunately I get the RuntimeException: cannot instance WorkItem...

**UPDATE2: STACK TRACE**

```
2016-09-13 11:49:59,355 ERROR [org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl] (default task-24) Deployment of unit testing:testing-work-item-handler:1.0 failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot instance WorkItemHandler bpmstest.test.WI: org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.exception.DeploymentException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot instance WorkItemHandler bpmstest.test.WI
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl.java:203) [jbpm-console-ng-business-domain-backend-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl.java:158) [jbpm-console-ng-business-domain-backend-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl.process(DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl.java:517) [jbpm-console-ng-business-domain-backend-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.process(Unknown Source) [jbpm-console-ng-business-domain-backend-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.BuildServiceImpl.doBuildAndDeploy(BuildServiceImpl.java:178) [kie-wb-common-services-backend-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.BuildServiceImpl.buildAndDeploy(BuildServiceImpl.java:134) [kie-wb-common-services-backend-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.BuildServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.buildAndDeploy(Unknown Source) [kie-wb-common-services-backend-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_72]
    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.io.AbstractRPCMethodCallback.invokeMethodFromMessage(AbstractRPCMethodCallback.java:48) [errai-bus-3.2.3.Final.jar:3.2.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.io.ValueReplyRPCEndpointCallback.callback(ValueReplyRPCEndpointCallback.java:22) [errai-bus-3.2.3.Final.jar:3.2.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.io.RemoteServiceCallback.callback(RemoteServiceCallback.java:54) [errai-bus-3.2.3.Final.jar:3.2.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.CDIExtensionPoints$2.callback(CDIExtensionPoints.java:410) [errai-weld-integration-3.2.3.Final.jar:3.2.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.DeliveryPlan.deliver(DeliveryPlan.java:47) [errai-bus-3.2.3.Final.jar:3.2.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.ServerMessageBusImpl.sendGlobal(ServerMessageBusImpl.java:296) [errai-bus-3.2.3.Final.jar:3.2.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.SimpleDispatcher.dispatchGlobal(SimpleDispatcher.java:46) [errai-bus-3.2.3.Final.jar:3.2.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.service.ErraiServiceImpl.store(ErraiServiceImpl.java:97) [errai-bus-3.2.3.Final.jar:3.2.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.service.ErraiServiceImpl.store(ErraiServiceImpl.java:114) [errai-bus-3.2.3.Final.jar:3.2.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.servlet.DefaultBlockingServlet.doPost(DefaultBlockingServlet.java:142) [errai-bus-3.2.3.Final.jar:3.2.3.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.uberfire.ext.security.server.SecureHeadersFilter.doFilter(SecureHeadersFilter.java:69) [uberfire-servlet-security-0.8.0.Final.jar:0.8.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.uberfire.ext.security.server.SecurityIntegrationFilter.doFilter(SecurityIntegrationFilter.java:61) [uberfire-servlet-security-0.8.0.Final.jar:0.8.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:248) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:167) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:761) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_72]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot instance WorkItemHandler bpmstest.test.WI
    at org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.KModuleDeploymentService.deploy(KModuleDeploymentService.java:201) [jbpm-kie-services-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.jbpm.services.cdi.impl.DeploymentServiceCDIImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deploy(Unknown Source) [jbpm-services-cdi-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl.java:194) [jbpm-console-ng-business-domain-backend-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot instance WorkItemHandler bpmstest.test.WI
    at org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.AbstractDeploymentService.commonDeploy(AbstractDeploymentService.java:161) [jbpm-kie-services-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.KModuleDeploymentService.deploy(KModuleDeploymentService.java:196) [jbpm-kie-services-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot instance WorkItemHandler bpmstest.test.WI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either extend [AbstractWorkItemHandler](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/6.4.x/jbpm-workitems/src/main/java/org/jbpm/process/workitem/AbstractWorkItemHandler.java) or implement your work item handler in a similar way. Then just pass `ksession` instance as a parameter of its constructor when you register it. Once you have a reference to KIE session, you can get global variables calling its `getGlobals()` method.

Comment: Hey Thomas, how could I properly extend AbstractWorkItem class?
I make it as follows: 
public class WI extends AbstractWorkItemHandler {
 public WI(StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession) {
  super(ksession);
 }
KieSession kSession = getSession(); 
ProcessContext context = new ProcessContext(kSession);
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
public void executeWorkItem(WorkItem workItem, WorkItemManager manager) {
params.put("lane", context.getNodeInstance().getNode().getMetaData().get("Lane").toString());
manager.completeWorkItem(workItem.getId(), params);}

Comment: But unfortunately I get a RuntimeException trying to build and deploy my project in Kie WorkBench.
Have I properly understood, that actual StatefulKnowledgeSession should be injected by creating an instance of my WI - class? Or something wrong with my code?

Comment: Do you register your work item handler globally in kie-wb.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/kie-wb-deployment-descriptor.xml or only for your project directly in KIE Workbench? In any case have a look at other work item handlers there and see how ksession is passed to their constructors.

Comment: I've tried to register it as other WItems are respectively their Constructors in kie-deployment-descriptor.xml, namely as follows: new package.WI(ksession);
Unfortunately it gets also not be deployed and throws the same RuntimeException: cannot instance WorkItem

Comment: Can you please upload somewhere your exception stack trace and post a link here? It is hard to say what can be wrong. Do you set unique name of your work item handler? Have you uploaded the JAR file with your work item handler implementation to KIE Workbench?

Comment: I've added stack trace. Sure, I do set a unique name and add as dependency my .jar file. I mean, I can without any problem deploy an App with a process, where I use my CustomWorkItem, which implements WorkItemHandler, and it works perfect. But it is not the case with AbstractWorkItemHandler. I have also checked maven repository, cause for AbstractWorkItemHandler I need to use additional dependence, namely jbpm-workitems, it is also on the server, where I deploy my app in .m2 - folder.

Comment: I do not know if this solves your problem but you should move initialization of `ksession` and `context` to the constructor. Because otherwise they are initialized before the constructor with values you do not expect there.

Answer (score 0):

The workitem should extends from AbstractWorkItemHandler to have the access to NodeInstance and kieSession

in execute you can do that :

List variables =
((VariableScope) ((NodeInstanceImpl) getNodeInstance(workItem)).resolveContextInstance(VariableScope.VARIABLE_SCOPE).get(0)).getVariables();